# One datasource for project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datasource, paradigms

I'm using wizard to add tables to my project to work with them. Is having just one datasource for project better way? At the moment there is only 5 tables.

---

**POST EDIT**
It's so cumbersome and I'm feeling myself going wrong way to use wizard, that makes another one dataset for every table, so I thought about just one dataset for my little application. But as I have little experience with ADO .NET, I hope to get advice here.

Comment: What is your actual problem / Issue..? what is it that you are truly trying to accomplish here.. please define your question more clearly

Comment: Is this LINQ2SQL or EF ? You can drag tables from the Server Explorer to the design surface. (Pro tip: Don't use the wizards when you can avoid it. It is not really productive).

Comment: @driis This is not Linq2SQL or EF. Just pure datasets, table adapters, datagridviews and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps is better to use [Entity Framework 4.1 / 4.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696172%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure it's good for my little application? There is only 5 tables. Only basic CRUD operations needed and nothing else.

Comment: Do you have any example of code or written explanation of when you would want to Create, Update, Delete.. what are the conditions.. and I think that it would be easier for us to guide you.. your question is still a bit vague..

Comment: @kseen Yes. I am sure. Today you have 5 tables and 1 month later 10 tables and 100% CRUD for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I find it's much easier to maintain an application when features of the system are isolated from one another. So in this instance having a dataset, one for each way the system is accessed, would make it easier to maintain.

an example of how this plays out:

1. a context to search for customers
2. a context to allow a customer to place an order
3. a context to add a product to a customer's shopping cart

this is probably overkill for a system of 5 tables, but if you can train yourself to think in context specific usages, it makes it much easier to expand and change the system moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use typed DataSet instead of EF or Linq2Sql just add new DataSet to your project, open it, right click and Add->TableAdapter, add all tables you need.